# Is it possible to create a new distribution in WinBUGS

Tags: winbugs

Normally, the model is generated based on some available distributions in WinBUGS, what if we need the parameters to be sampled from other specific distributions.

Is it possible to create a new distribution in WinBUGS

Answer (score 1):

If you can calculate the log likelihood in your model, then you can use the ones/zeros trick in WinBUGS to define a custom distribution - see http://users.aims.ac.za/~mackay/BUGS/Manuals/Tricks.html

If you are familiar with C++ coding, then a better solution is to implement a module containing your distribution in JAGS (rather than WinBUGS) - see http://www.cidlab.com/prints/wabersich2013extending.pdf

The easiest way to implement a module in JAGS is by embedding it within an R package - take a look at the module inside the runjags package (on CRAN) to get you started.  This removes a lot of the pain of getting the module to compile and install.